# Recent grad looking for advice on how choose between IT and CS by testing CS skills

Tags: career-development

I am currently applying for jobs. I am looking for some career advice.

My question is how can I figure out if I should pursue IT and CS related jobs or only IT?

What I’m thinking is that I will test myself somehow. If I do well enough I will apply for CS related jobs. I’m not sure exactly how to do this yet. A couple ideas are HackerRank or the book Cracking the Coding Interview.

**Some More Info**

**Plans**

Plan A

Work in IT for now, maybe try something more CS related later on.

Plan B

Try to find a CS job now and hope for the best.

Plan C

Never pursue CS.

**Basic Information**

I have a degree in Applied Computing Technology. It was a mix of business IT classes and CS classes. My cumulative grade point average is 2.612. My major GPA is 2.859. I have one year of IT experience as a technician.

The problem is I don’t know if it would be ethical for me to take a CS job. I had a lot going on personally while I was trying to obtain my degree. Still I need to be able perform at a certain level and I don’t want to put any lives in danger.

**Background**

In middle school and high school I did have some social difficulties and it is still something I am working to improve. Besides school about all I did was watch TV, play video games, and browse the internet. Thankfully I’ve gotten these habits basically under control. I procrastinated on most assignments and that habit carried forward into college.

In college, on almost every programming assignment I would rely heavily on the internet and TA. To be perfectly honest, I did copy paste code sometimes and then modify it for my use case. I would make an attempt to at least try to understand the code. I can think of a couple assignments that I came close to borderline cheating on. I did not get any help from my peers as I was a shut in.

There was one point where I was considering leaving school and working. I went to talk to some sort of last chance counselor at my school. She learned about my past and introduced me to the idea of a disability and accommodations. I still ended up taking a break from school. When I came back I had accommodations for the remainder of college. I used the extra time on tests (most of the time I only used 25% to 50% extra time and not the full double time I was allowed) and assignment extensions a couple times. I still don’t know if my mental health was a legitimate reason or an excuse that I let myself believe. This is a big part of the reason I am on the fence about pursuing CS.

I believe a large part of my problem was poor character development. I may also have some slight developmental disability but I refuse to let it hold me back or use it as an excuse any longer. Going forward I will not be asking for any accommodations. Moral of the story is I definitely had some growing up to do.

**Some other details:**

It took me longer then most to finish college (7 years). I always struggled with math classes which is part of the reason I chose my degree. I did take Adderal for about a year to see if it would help with school. I am no longer going to take it. My school is getting rid of my degree (If that says anything).

**Now**

Although it is somewhat important to me I’m not in it for the money. What ever I end up doing I want to have some natural ability for it so I’m not over stressed.

At this point. I can write very basic code from scratch. I can usually understand what code does if I look at it long enough. If I were to get a developer job I would probably need the internet to be successful. At best I would be a mediocre developer. I am working on critical thinking and problem solving skills. I am slowly getting better. I am willing to work to improve what I can. Another option would be web development although I am a little burnt out on it.

My original question - how can I figure out if I should pursue IT and CS related jobs or only IT?

All I've come up with is testing my CS skills.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: I'm in the United States.

Comment: **Please define the difference between IT and CS**. For example, is working on and contributing to the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler "information technology" or "computer science"? Is contributing to the [Linux kernel](http://kernel.org/) IT or CS? IMNSHO, it is a mixture of both. Consider also starting a PhD.

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice?

Comment: I didn't. I changed my original question. I tried to make it clear that I was asking how to make the decision and not what decision to make. The best advice I was given was to do a more in-depth personal project. That should help me figure out if I should pursue something more CS heavy.

Comment: I thought about it some more and doing something from scratch might not be realistic. I was thinking of finding an interesting project on GitHub and then doing some combination of re-doing parts of it, repurposing it, or adding to it.

Answer (score 5):

> A couple ideas are HackerRank or the book Cracking the Coding Interview.

HackerRank and Cracking the Coding Interview have very little to do with day to day software development. The topics covered in those are fairly niche and the topics are mostly for interviews, which like in many other fields, are often disconnected from the actual job. Don't use them to determine if you can be a software developer. Most developers can't do what is in Cracking the Coding Interview without a lot of prep.

Instead, go to Udemy, pick a course on something like web development, and see if you can build the projects in it.

> Still I need to be able perform at a certain level and I don’t want to put any lives in danger.

Just do not work for Boeing and you should be ok. 99% of software has no way to cause any physical harm.

> In college, on almost every programming assignment I would rely heavily on the internet and TA.

We call that Stack Overflow, which you almost certainly know. Most of us use it a lot too. If not, we go to other references. The idea of a developer just sitting down and cranking out code without looking something up is Hollywood nonsense. It is perfectly reasonable to look things up. I studied in a traditional engineering program and it was emphasized several times that it would be incompetent to not look things up regularly (obviously from credible sources).  We also regularly ask for help from other members on our teams. Software development is often a team activity.

> I always struggled with math classes which is part of the reason I chose my degree.

Most software jobs involve no calculus. Can you handle algebra? That is the level most are at.

> It took me longer then most to finish college (7 years).

College requires you get something right the first time you are tested on it. Software can have an error, the error can be fixed, and you just keep trying until it succeeded. Perhaps not on some mega codebases, but most are not those.

> If I were to get a developer job I would probably need the internet to be successful.

Stack Overflow is proof that using the internet to find help is perfectly ok.

Do a Udemy course and see if you can build software. If so, start applying for junior developer jobs.

Comment: I think I've made my decision. I'm going to pursue IT for now and do a more in depth CS project in my own time. If I actually do it and am pleased with the result I will give something more CS intensive a try in the future. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're a conscientious person who's worked to improve his approach to things, legitimately wants to be good at what he does, and is concerned for the well-being of others. Keep working at it, show employers your best side and your willingness to learn, and hope for the best if it's what you want to do.

No one is likely to put you in a place where you could put others' lives in danger if they evaluate you as not ready for that responsibility. (Just don't cheat to be put in such a position!)

If you need more education or experience, you'll find out once you apply and interview. Then go get it if CS is what you want to do.